# How to find element in frame in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I used below code for finding the element in the frame but I got the error
kindly explain by this framebyinedex, framebystring, framebywebelement:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Framebyindex 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver f1=new FirefoxDriver();
        f1.get("http://spicareers.com/spicareers/");
        f1.switchTo().frame(1);
        f1.findElement(By.linkText(" .Net - Senior Developer ")).click();
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:     Unable to locate element:     {"method":"link text","selector":" .Net - Senior  Developer "}

Comment: Give us please HTML code of the page.

Comment: Try to remove white spaces.

Comment: by removing white spaces i got the answer thank u, kindly explain how to find frame names

Comment: Frame names you can find in HTML code.

Answer (score 3):

Before you have to switch to the frame:

```
        driver.get("http://spicareers.com/spicareers/");
        WebElement frame= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='JRAMPSMainFrame']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

and after you could try with:

```
        WebElement myEl= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), ' .Net - Senior Developer ')]"));
        myEl.click();
```

Finally, if you want to switch back:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**EDIT**

The interested element is inside the iframe with name "JRAMPSMainFrame". If you inspect your html, you could notice this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: in my HTML code two frame tags are there how do i find the correct frame name, why should not be the frame name as "JRAMPSHeader" in the html code

Comment: @PrakashMohanraj Yes, in your html there are 2 iframe. You can "locate" the interested iframe by index (as you made in your code) or (for example) by the "name" attribute (that is different), as I made in my example.

Comment: @PrakashMohanraj, If you was wondering about why the element is inside the iframe with name "JRAMPSMainFrame", I've just edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchElementException` simply means that, the selenium did not detect a link with the text as you asked it.

I suggest you to work with use `by.xpath` to resolve it. To get the xpath of the element, take the below steps on your `chrome`, or `firefox` browser.

1. Right click on the element (here the link)
2. Click on `inspect`. It opens the inspect console (Elements tab) in your browser, and highlights the clicked element.
3. Right click on the element in the elements tab
4. Choose copy
5. Copy Xpath
6. In your code, replace `By.linkText` with `By.xpath`
7. Paste the value as an string into the `xpath("you paste here")`

Or simpler, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZnuIirVvw8) video

Comment: how to use xpath on the frame?

Comment: @Salman your answer doesn't work because the interested element is inside an iframe.

Comment: @Salman try and verify. The url is in the code snippet of the question.

Comment: Yes, of course. But before he has to switch to the interested iframe

Comment: @DavidePatti Did you notice, he has tried to switch to the frame using the `f1.switchTo().frame(1);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have selected a wrong frame or the link text might contain more spaces.

Chrome developer tools is your best friend in this situation. Use it to find the element correctly and to identify the frame.

> SELECT FRAME

1. Open the application in chrome.
2. Open developer tools
3. Click Console tab of developer tool
4. Select you frame from the drop down
   [image: frame selector]

In the above picture there is only one frame.

> FIND ELEMENT

1. After selecting the frame, type `$x("//a[normalize-space(.) = '.Net - Senior Developer']")` to check your xpath.

`$x("")` is the function for checking xpath in browser.

Using the above mechanism find the frame and the element.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the `HTML` of `http://spicareers.com/spicareers/` the `WebElement` with text as `.Net - Senior Developer` is within an `<iframe>` tag. So before accessing the intended `WebElement` we have to switch to the `frame` first either through the `frame_name`, `frame_id` or `frame_index` as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://spicareers.com/spicareers/");
driver.switchTo().frame("JRAMPSMainFrame"); //using "frame_name"
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), ' .Net - Senior Developer ')]"));
elem.click();
```

Comment: in my HTML code two frame tags are there how do i find the correct frame name, why should not be the frame name as "JRAMPSHeader" in the html code

Comment: how u r saying ".Net - Senior Developer" is in <iframe> tag,explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, First enter into the frame using `name` locator and try to locate the career option then

Try this code, I have modified your code:

```
public class Framebyindex 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver f1=new FirefoxDriver();
        f1.get("http://spicareers.com/spicareers/");
        f1.switchTo().frame( f1.findElement(By.name("JRAMPSMainFrame")));
WebElement netCareer= f1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), ' .Net - Senior Developer ')]"));
        netCareer.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: in my HTML code two frame tags are there how do i find the correct frame name, why should not be the frame name as "JRAMPSHeader" in the html code

Comment: Whatever is correct you can use.aa I think my frame name is correct

Answer (score 0):

By using:
https://github.com/nick318/FindElementInFrames

you can write following:

```
    SearchByFramesFactory searchFactory = new SearchByFramesFactory(driver);
    
    SearchByFrames searchInFrame = searchFactory.search(() -> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), ' .Net - Senior Developer ')]")));
    searchInFrame.getElem().ifPresent(WebElement::click);
```